# Why does increasing gas pipe volume at the meter work?

Tags: natural-gas

The supply lines at my gas meter are branched and then up-sized.

How does this increase gas volume to downstream appliances?

[image: gas meter pipes]

Comment: Pressure and volume

Comment: How do you know that the volume is getting increased?

Comment: @RMDman increased pipe size = larger volume

Comment: @Traveler, that is theoretical.  We do not know for fact that the volume is increased, or why it may be an issue.

Comment: @RMDman it is not theoretical, it is practical, why else there are different pipe sizes ?

Comment: Volume is confusing here.  Obviously the interior volume of the pipes is increased.  But what the asker seems to want to know is how it increases the volume of gas that reaches the appliances.  I.e. how it increases flow.  Note that if this were a liquid, then it wouldn't work that way.  Water doesn't expand or contract significantly based on pressure.  Even with a gas, I'm not sure that it significantly increases flow.  It would increase the volume after the meter, but the flow might be the same with smaller pipes.  I.e. the increased pipe size may do nothing of importance here.

Comment: @mdfst13 It does. [Darcy-Weisbach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darcy–Weisbach_equation).

Comment: @user71659  That link seems to say that bigger pipes allow more flow.  But the question here is if a bigger pipe significantly increases the flow if after a smaller section of pipe that restricts it.  It does seem to suggest that the reduced friction would produce a small increase in flow, but I don't know that it would significantly increase it.  If you have math that demonstrates that, it would be helpful to put it in the form of an answer.  Note that by significant, I mean proportionate to the increase of the cross area of the pipe.  I.e. doubling the cross area should nearly double flow.

Comment: @mdfst13 Think about it like wire. You get a pressure drop (resistance) per unit length, the L term in Darcy-Weisbach. The overall pressure drop at the end is merely the sum of pressure drops, thus a short run of narrow pipe has less of an effect than a long run.

Comment: Darcy-Weisbach applies here only in that you have less resistance from a larger pipe.  The flow rate of gas will still remain the same—your supply line pressure is what it is.  It's just a question of whether the lower resistance of the larger pipe is can overcome the higher resistance added by expansion and contraction losses.